# Store Voting Information - Database Outline

Tags: mysql, database, data-structures

Summary: What is the most efficient way to store information similar to the like system on FB. Aka, a tally of likes is kept, the person who like it is kept etc.

It needs to be associated with a user id so as to know who liked it. The issue is, do you have a column that has a comma delimited list of the id of things that were liked, or do you have a separate column for each like (way too many columns). The info that's stored would be a boolean value (1/0) but needs to be associated with the user as well as the "page" that was liked.

My thought was this:

Column name = likes eg.:

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

Aka, the user has "like" the pages that have an id of 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. To calculate total "likes" a tally would need to be taken and then stored in a database associated with the pages themselves (table already exists).

That seems the best way to me but is there a better option that anyone can think of?

P.S. I'm not doing FB likes but it's the easiest explanation.

EDIT: Similar idea to the plus/neg here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case the best way would be to create a new table to keep track of the likes. So supposing you have table `posts`, which has a column `post_id` which contains all the posts (on which the users can vote). And you have another table `users` with a column `user_id`, which contains all the users.

You should create a table `likes` which has at least two columns, something like `like_postid` and `like_userid`. Now, everytime a user likes a post create a new row in this table with the id of the post (the value of `post_id` from `posts`) that is liked and the id of the user (the value of `user_id` from `users`) that likes the post. Of course you can enter some more columns in the `likes` table (for instance to keep track of when a like is created).

What you have here is called a [many-to-many relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29). Google it to get some more information about it and to find some more advice on how to implement them correctly (you will find that a comma seperated lists of id's will not be one of the best practices).

Update based on comments:
If I'm correct; you want to get a list of all users (ordered by name) who have voted on an artist. You should do that something like:

```
SELECT Artists.Name, User.Name
FROM Artists
JOIN Votes
    ON Votes.page_ID = Artists.ID
JOIN Users
    ON Votes.Votes_Userid = Users.User_ID
WHERE Artists.Name = "dfgdfg"
ORDER BY Users.Users_Name
```

There a strange thing here; the column in your Votes table which contains the artist id seems to be called `page_ID`. Also you're a bit inconsistent in column names (not really bad, but something to keep in mind if you want to be able to understand your code after leaving it alone for 6 months). In your comment you say that you only make one join, but you actually do two joins. If you specify two table names (like you do: `JOIN Users, Votes` SQL actually joins these two tables.

Based on the query you posted in the comments I can tell you haven't got much experience using joins. I suggest you read up on how to use them, it will really improve your ability to write good code.

Comment: Sounds great. Thanks :) Will begin planning it and see how I go :)

Comment: My thoughts atm are to use a mysql statement similar to this: SELECT Artists.Name, User_Name, Votes_vote
FROM Artists WHERE Artists.Name = "dfgdfg"
JOIN Users, Votes
ON Artists.ID = Votes.page_ID, Users.User_ID = Votes.Votes_Userid
ORDER BY User_Name There is most likely an issue in terms of the join as I believe you can only join one table through the process, but this would be the idea. Would that be right?

Comment: I think I've got the basic jist of it (got a query to work so that's good). I have dealt with joins in the past though have no clue with the syntax, but understand (some) of how they operate in a general capacity. Will read up on them though as well as applying that to what I'm dealing with etc. And yah, was trying to avoid confusion so was still using some of your names etc (though probably created more confusion with my names). Thanks for the help :) Will work through it more and will post up finished product query wise when I get to that stage :)

Comment: you probably also want to consider how you count the votes - you probably want results like "artist Bob", "400 likes" - "artist Mary", "600 likes".

Comment: Yep, that's why in my artists table I will have a votes column. A query will be run every x minutes to tally the number of votes etc. Will put up a schema to show how I'm thinking once I'm finished.